# How to organize two input fields with dash between in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have two input fields with size 2 and size 7 next to each other. Also, there should be a dash between two input fields. Here is example of what I have so far:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     This is some title?
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="valid" /> <strong>Yes</strong></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label><u>System ID:</u></label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
         <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text"  name="system_id_1" value="56" size="2" maxlength="2">
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4">
         <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="system_id_2" value="2345778" size="7" maxlength="7">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Record Number:</label>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="recnum" value="879043512" size="9" maxlength="9" />
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Between input field `system_id_1` and `system_id_2` I would like to have a dash like this `-`. Is it possible to insert the dash? Also, the size of the input fields is not accurate. How to set the size to match the number of characters in the size attribute?

Comment: u can use css to position it.

Comment: you can do that, using pseudo-class `:after`. I have made a working snippet below. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

Html Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Weather-graphic</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        This is some title?
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="valid" /> <strong>Yes</strong></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><u>System ID:</u></label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2 system_id_1">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text"  name="system_id_1" value="56" size="2" maxlength="2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-1 dash">
                                <p>&mdash;</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 system_id_2">
                                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="system_id_2" value="2345778" size="7" maxlength="7">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Record Number:</label>
                        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="recnum" value="879043512" size="9" maxlength="9" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
</body>
</html>
```

Css Code:

```
.system_id_1{
   width:12% !important;
} 
.system_id_2{
    width:18% !important;
} 
.dash {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    width: 2.33% !important;
}
```

I hope it helps you !

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using pseudo class `:after` .Below is the working snippet

```css
.dash:after {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  content: "—";
  top: 0px;
  left: -8px;
 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          This is some title?
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="valid" /> <strong>Yes</strong></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label><u>System ID:</u></label>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="system_id_1" value="56" size="2" maxlength="2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 dash">
              <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="system_id_2" value="2345778" size="7" maxlength="7">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Record Number:</label>
          <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="recnum" value="879043512" size="9" maxlength="9" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```